# Grails/Groovy number seperator gets lost calling $.getJSON

Tags: json, grails, google-maps-api-3, groovy

i am trying to pass a JSON object with coordinates from my controller to my view and render it on a google-map.
My controller returns the coordinates in a correct way with number sperators
 e.g.: "lat":6.12345  , but after calling the function with $.getJSON, the lat in the jqueryobject has no seperator
 e.g.: "lat":612345
My Controller looks like:

```
def eventsJson = {
    def list = []
    events.each { event ->
        list.push([
                name: event?.name as String
                ,lat:  event?.place?.latitude as Float
                ,lon:  event?.place?.longitude as Float
        ])
    }
    render(list as JSON)
}
```

My Jquery looks like:

```
$.getJSON("event/eventsJson", function (data) { 
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                alert(item.lon);
                var tmp = {lat: item.lat, lng: item.lon};
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: tmp,
                    map: map
                    });


    });
});
```

I'm greateful for any comments and suggestions...! :)

Comment: Not the issue, but why are you doing `event?.place?.latitude as Float`?  What type *is* `event.place.latitude`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand `event?.place?.latitude` and `event?.place?.longitude`.
I'm considering `event` and `place` are different domains and have relation between them.

So you need to change your `EventController` as follows:

first you need to import `import grails.converters.JSON`

```
def eventsJson = {
HashMap eventsMap = new events()
List eventsList = Events.list()

eventsMap.events= eventsList .collect {event->
return [name: event.name, lat: event.place.latitude, lon: event.place.longitude]
}

render eventsMap as JSON
```

and `gsp` jQuery as follows:

```
$.getJSON("event/eventsJson", function (data) { 
    $.each(data.eventsMap, function (i, item) {
                var tmp = {lat: item.lat, lng: item.lon};
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: tmp,
                    map: map
                    });


    });
});
```

I'm not sure with jQuery. So please Check and modify according to requirement.